# How to have a Raster output of a ppm model in spastat

Tags: raster, r, model, spatstat

I am trying to compare the outputs of species distribution models. My current code uses the following function to calculate TSS scores.

```
TSS_Score<-function(TrueBinary, Raster) {

  Raster[]<-as.numeric(Raster[] > 0.5)

  ConfusionMatrix<-crosstab(TrueBinary,Raster)

  a<-ConfusionMatrix[2,2]

  b<-ConfusionMatrix[2,1]

  c<-ConfusionMatrix[1,2]

  d<-ConfusionMatrix[1,1]

  Sensitivity<-a/(a+c)

  Specificity<-d/(b+d)

  TSS<-Sensitivity+Specificity-1

  return(TSS)
}
```

This code works but I need a raster as the model output for it to work. I have run a `ppm` model from `spatstat` and then used the `predict.ppm` function. However the output of `predict.ppm` is an `image` class.

Is there anyway to get a Raster as a predict output?

Or to convert the image into a raster?

EDIT: Here is the code for my ppm model. The covariates are images files as the function doesn't seem to take rasters?

> PPMmodel<-ppm(PointsPPP, ~slope, covariates = list(slope =
>
> AMtemp,MDRtemp,Isotherm,AMprecip,SeasonPrecip, TreeCover50))
>
> predictPPM<-predict(PPMmodel)
>
> predictPPM
>
> real-valued pixel image
>
> 128 x 128 pixel array (ny, nx)
>
> enclosing rectangle: [92.192, 141.01] x [-10.999, 28.549] units

Comment: The output of predict.ppm can be all sorts of things - could you show us what yours is? Generally you can turn spatstat image classes into matrices with `as.matrix` and get the coordinates from the object too, which is sufficient to create raster classes.

Comment: @Spacedman I have added the modeling code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something from `example(predict.ppm)` that looks like your object:

```
> trend
real-valued pixel image
32 x 32 pixel array (ny, nx)
enclosing rectangle: [0, 1] x [0, 1] units
```

and here is what happens when you call `raster` from the `raster` package on it:

```
> raster(trend)
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 32, 32, 1024  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.03125, 0.03125  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 61.62107, 107.6241  (min, max)
```

which was a very pleasant surprise.

Comment: Interesting...I wouldn't expect that at all....Thanks for looking at that! Saving that as .grd file will solve my problem! Thank you!